# Help regarding website based javascript using 0x for order trades

Tags: 0x

Hey I apologize in advance, I am very new to a lot of the development regarding this subject. I have written my own erc20 token and was trying to find a way to easily trade it. I am aware of the many AMM exchanges, however I feel that the order system from 0x would fit better to the token. I am having difficulty trying to incorporate the 0x API into my website to allow these trades. Many tutorials or guides I have found use Node.js or functions only available to it. Is it possible at all to use the functionality of 0x's API from a standard website and if so, how would these functions be called?

Answer (score 0):

The [0x instant project](https://github.com/0xProject/0x-instant/blob/master/docs/integrate-instant.mdx) might be useful in your situation. [0x instant's repo](https://github.com/0xProject/0x-instant/blob/master/docs/integrate-instant.mdx)

As the description reads -
"0x Instant is a product from the 0x core team that offers a convenient way for people to get access to a wide variety of tokens and other crypto-assets in just a few clicks. Developers can integrate the free, open source library into their applications or websites in order to both offer seamless access to crypto-assets, as well as gain a new source of revenue, with just a few lines of code...0x Instant UI powered by 0x API are bundled together in a convenient JS package for you".

It is live on mainnet and ropsten. Here is a live example of it used for [dexkit](https://dexkit-storage.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/zrx/v4/index.html)